# Preferred way to clean-up resources in Java 1.6

Tags: java, idioms

I regularly see this style of resource clean-up:

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    // ...
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

I have always used the following style:

```
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    // ...
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

But am I missing something? Is there an advantage to the former that I'm not seeing?

Comment: You might be missing something... `new FileInputStream()` can throw FileNotFoundException. So that exception won't be catched in that block of code, but it will be propagated to the caller.

Comment: @Augusto neither examples catch the FileNotFoundException. not sure if that was intentional however.

Comment: I think the former is  only meaningful if it also has a `catch` block. In other cases, your form is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect its to avoid having two nested try/catch blocks instead of one.

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    // ...
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    // handle exception.
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
}
```

The second case is incomplete.

```
try {
    final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        // ...
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

If you have multiple files, this could get really messy.

Comment: I like this answer, even though it is short and missing explanations.

Comment: Can you show what the exception handling looks like for the other version too? Is it really any cleaner?

Comment: @aetheria The first example is complete, you don't need an outer catch.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete"? The first version does not have any catch block!

Comment: @aetheria It depends on your assumptions, but if they are the same the first example should looks as I have added.

Comment: Thanks, but as I suspected, your version does not handle the IOException potentially thrown by the `in.close()`.

Comment: @aetheria For this reason a helper method is often used. This way the IOException caught will be from the try block, not the close().

Comment: `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` is cheating! You're just hiding another try..catch. And, more seriously, you're not handling the exception, you're swallowing it.

Comment: Never the less its common practice because such an exception is rare and often due to the previous exception which gives you the real cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that in the first example you have some other code before defining *in* that gets you out of the try block. If you get to the finally without in been defined you will get a NullPointerException when trying to close it. So you will have to make the check to avoid errors like that.

Comment: Yes, but `in` cannot be `null` in my version.

Answer (score 0):

The `null` check here for the `InputStream` is necessary as it is possible that the variable might not be assigned. In this case a NullPointerException would be thrown when attempting to close it when calling:

```
in.close();
```

In the 2nd block *outside* of the try/catch block:

```
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    // ...
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

You can easily encounter other exceptions before entering the block and the `InputStream` is never closed.

Comment: `in` is assigned directly before the try. It cannot be `null`.

Comment: @aetheria the `//...` can make it null

Answer (score 0):

The second one will not compile since the constructor of [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29) can throw a `FileNotFoundException`, thus you'd need an extra `try-catch` block, unless of course, the method itself throws it.

Another common idiom is to write a `closeQuietly()` method to avoid having to write the `if (is != null)` check all over your `finally` blocks. This is what Apache Common's [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29) does:

```
public static void closeQuietly(InputStream input) {
  try {
    if (input != null) {
      input.close();
    }
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    // ignore
  }
}
```

<sub>Also note that *since* Java 7, you can use the following:</sub>

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
} catch (final FileNotFoundException | IOException ex) { 
}
```

Comment: Sure, I haven't shown the code it sits in, but the method is declared to throw `IOException` so it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple example, And may not create a problem as you are creating `InputStream` in same bloke. But if `InputStream` is closed because of some `Exception or` other fault, in that case your code will fail, So its always better to check if `InputStream` is available

Comment: My code won't fail. Most streams allow `close()` to be called multiple times, but at the worst, the call to `close()` may throw an `IOException`, but that's fine. The exception can be handled further up the call-stack just like any other `IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you need to open not one, but two files. You would do

```
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file1);
final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file2);
try {
    // ...
} finally {
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

If the `out` fails to open, you will get an exception and because it's out of the `try` block `in` won't be closed in the `finally` block.

In the other method:

```
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(file1);
    out = new FileOutputStream(file2);
    // ...
} finally {
    if (out != null) out.close();
    if (in != null) in.close();
}
```

If `out` fails to open, you will go to the `finally` block and close both streams. If `in` fails to open, you will go to the finally block, and free only `in` - because `out==null`.

**edit**

As the aetheria mentioned, that code wouldn't work because `close()` throws exception in Java. It can easily be fixed by putting each resource release in it's own `try`-`catch` block:

```
InputStream  in  = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(file1);
    out = new FileOutputStream(file2);
    // ...
} finally {
    try{ out.close(); }catch(Exception e){}
    try{ in.close();  }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

I ditched the null checking - if `in` or `out` is null, it'll throw a `NullPointerException` that will be ignored. And the reason I ignore `close` exceptions is that disposal methods shouldn't throw exceptions in the first place. If handling closing exceptions is required, you can always close the streams again, **after** the `finally` block. That way, any stream that *can* be closed will be closed already(so you wouldn't have to worry about it), and you can handle any exceptions from `close` more elegantly.

Now, aetheria also suggested to put a separate `try`-`finally` block for each resource that would look like this:

```
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file1);
try {
    final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file2);
    try {
        // ...
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

This works, but even with only two resources, it's much less elegant, as it splits the allocations and releasing code, making it harder to keep track of it(in my opinion, at least).

Comment: This code contains bugs: if `out.close()` throws an `IOException` you will never close `in`.

Comment: To add to my last comment. I would **not** do what you suggest I would do at the top of your question. I would have separate `try..finally` blocks for each stream.

Comment: You're right, but I'd rather blame this on Java than admitting my own mistake. Anyways, I'v updated the answer.